# Trying to extract data from mdb file upon selecting the file in a listbox

Tags: vb.net-2010

[image: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/skvwade6p5cjnw0/AAAfe-iHBLieElNfIBAy4bTAa?dl=0]

I am generating a new project from an existing template every time i click on create and renaming the same as a new project name (an mdb file)in the same directory. The details mentioned in to the right namely location, engineer, contractor etc are stored in this mdb file at this instance.- so far i am successful....

Now that i have the list of projects listed in my list box I would like to select any one and I wish to see the details for the same to my right.
I've posted a link having a .bmp image of the form. Help is highly appreciated.

Comment: If you are able to store the data in your form to an mdb file, you should be able to read it too assuming you have r/w access. Can you give more information about how you are saving the file?

Comment: Dear Anand,   Could not reply earlier apologies. Just wanted to to update that I have sorted out the problem thank you. Need help to close this discussion please advise. Would it be helpful if i posted the code on line ? Do advise

Comment: If you have the answer, post it and mark it as answer. It may help someone else

Comment: unable to upload hence sharing the dropbox link https://www.dropbox.com/s/ur7kisjby8xzqb5/New%20Text%20Document.txt?dl=0